# Using MVC4 with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have been successfully able to use the mvc4 simplemembership providers while using the 
SQL server.

However now I need to do the same using Oracle. Except for  this link below

http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/11/10/simplemembershipprovider-in-mvc4-for-mysql-oracle-and-more-with-llblgen/

i couldnt find any more information on how to do it or even, if this is possible.

Currently it fails when it tries to initialize the databaseconnection.

the connection string i am using in the webconfig is as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MembershipOracle" connectionString="data  source=data******com/data0****.com;password=Co***password;persist security info=True;user id=hereIzMyID" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
<add name="CoreEntitiesOracle" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CoreEntities.csdl|res://*/CoreEntities.ssdl|res://*/CoreEntities.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=data********com/data******.com;password=password;persist security info=True;user id=UserIDHere&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am pretty new to the world of mvc and dotnet etc. so any advice would be very helpful

Comment: Please provide conn string

Comment: Is this an Oracle source that exist remotely or one you configured locally?

Comment: This is an already existing Oracle source to which we connect remotely. Apart from the simplemembership everything else is working fine when we moved from sql to oracle.

Comment: what's the exception you get when trying to connect?

Comment: I get the Exception saying it cannot find the table User Profile.

Comment: Hi Guys, I just gave up using simplemembership provider and made my own custom provider to do the job. But however it would be great if we could have some information on how to make simplemembership provider work for oracle.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing when attempting to combine Oracle, EF 5.0, with MVC 4 and Visual Studio. I got the same error. It looks like that SimpleMembership is incompatible with Oracle at the moment?

Comment: I voted this up because it's an important question.

Comment: And I asked this recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613146/simplemembership-in-wcf-for-oracle

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this by using Devart libraries. Devart supports SimpleMembership Provider for MVC 4 for Oracle. You need to purchase for dotConnet for Oracle Professional. It will expose Devart.Data.Oracle.Web which is a replacement of WebMatrix.WebData. In your action filter "InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs" just toggle WebMatrix to Devart and have your solution up & running.